# What happens if you add an element to an existing MySQL set?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an existing MySQL database with a set type defined as: ('blue', 'orange', 'purple').

I have been asked to add 'green' to the set and want the set to be ('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'purple'), i.e. in alphabetic order.

What impact, if any, will this have on the existing database records? I think I read somewhere that the set value is stored as an offset into the set so if I insert 'green' in the way shown above will this cause records with fields set to 'orange' to point to the wrong set member? Or does everything magically sort itself out?

Comment: What a good reason to use reference tables instead of an enumerated types and sets.

Comment: Yes indeed but that is not an answer to my question.

Comment: according to the docs, bitmasks are stored in the table. So it seems like worst-case if there's no rebuild that handles this for you, you could follow the set change with an UPDATE statement that updates all the rows that had old-orange-now-green to remove orange and set green, and all the rows that had old-purple-now-orange to remove purple and set orange. Good docs at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will rebuild the whole table which is something that you might want to avoid. If you add the enum to the end the table will be unaffected.

Comment: So by rebuilding the whole table it will ensure the existing records still point to the correct set member? If so that sounds ok. What are the disadvantages of rebuilding?

Comment: Depends on the setup. For a big table it can be an expensive operation as everything blocks during the rebuild.

Comment: Might be ok for us because site is in development and making it hang shouldn't be a problem. Is the rebuild automatic?

Comment: Yes it is automatic (the ALTER TABLE takes care of it) but if you add now a table in production and you depend on the set to be ordered you are pretty much asking for trouble as in the future the rebuild might be a no-go. I would suggest to reconsider your design and not depend in an enum ordering.

Comment: I am using a package (grocerycrud) that lets admins add and edit database records easily and this relies on sets to make it easy for admins to enter information correctly, where relying in id references into another table would not so I think, overall, the disadvantages of changing the set in future are worth it. But I agree my implementation is not the best in many ways.